# How to have two different Firebase projects instances in one single app

Tags: android, firebase

Is it possible to have two different firebase projects instances in one single application? As there can be only one google-services.json.

I have an application where I need to access the two different Realtime Database so how is it possible to have different Firebase instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible. When using just a single database there is a single FirebaseApp object that you don't have to explicitly handle. If you want to connect to another database, you would simply configure that object manually, like this:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setApplicationId("YOUR_APP_ID") // Required for Analytics.
   .setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY") // Required for Auth.
   .setDatabaseUrl("https://YOUR_FIREBASE_URL.firebaseio.com/") // Required for RTDB.
   .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary");
```

Then you can access your app by passing in the name you set for the app, then pass that in the request for the database instance:

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
```

To be clear, you will still be able to access the other database in the standard way i.e.:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks @sam_c. Do you have any blog where I can find the code

Comment: Yeah, [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) is hosted by Google/Firebase.

Comment: @sam_c what about the `google-service-json` file? Can I have two of them in one single p project ?